# Can't make ViewBinding function properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

I am trying to build a mockup project to understand ViewBinding better so I can then forward the knowledge into my main project.

To better understand the problem I'm facing I will upload images of the running code portions I will show, so hopefully, this will highlight correctly the problem.

In case you need more files/code to have a clear idea of what is going on, I'll be happy to upload it.

```
class ElementAdapter(private var mElementList : MutableList<CardViewElement>, private val layoutId : Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>() {

    class ExampleViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var mImageView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_image_view)
        var mTextView1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1)
        var mTextView2: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text2)
    }

    private fun viewBind(parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return layoutInflater.inflate(layoutId, parent,false)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
        return ExampleViewHolder(viewBind(parent))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mElementList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = mElementList[position]
        Utils.bindImgView(holder.mImageView, currentItem.getImage())
        holder.mTextView1.text = currentItem.getText1()
        holder.mTextView2.text = currentItem.getText2()
    }

}
```

This is the result I get with this code, which is what I want to achieve as well with the ViewBinding (desired output!):

[image: DESIRED OUTPUT]

Now, I want to achieve the same exact results, but with ViewBinding (keep in mind I only posted what differs in the code, not the methods which are the exact same, like getItemCount() and onBindViewHolder())

```
class ElementAdapter(private var mElementList : MutableList<CardViewElement>, private var layoutId : Int) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var binding: MyRecyclerElementBinding

    class ExampleViewHolder(itemView: View) : ViewHolder(itemView) {
        lateinit var mImageView: ImageView
        lateinit var mTextView1: TextView
        lateinit var mTextView2: TextView
    }

    private fun viewBind(parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        binding = MyRecyclerElementBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
        val evh = ExampleViewHolder(viewBind(parent))
        evh.mImageView = binding.myImageView
        evh.mTextView1 = binding.text1
        evh.mTextView2 = binding.text2
        return evh
    }
}
```

(wrong output)
[image: WRONG OUTPUT]

Anyone has any idea how to fix this and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're referring to the grid item margins not being the same?

Comment: Yeah, as you can see every margin doesn't show up when i try to use ViewBinding

Comment: Did you try using padding in the grid list items rather than margins?

Comment: Yes i tried. But isn't it weird that the results changes when i try to implement the ViewBinding only? the XML never changes in this process.

EDIT: the items aren't in a grid, they are CardViews placed into RecyclerViews

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62708182/7434090

Comment: mmm sorry the stupid(maybe) question... but what container should be in my code?
```binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)```.

Comment: I would guess you'd want `binding = MyRecyclerElementBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)`

Comment: that's what i also tried, it says tho "found Activity, required ViewGroup", without an easy fix suggestion from Android Studio

Comment: But `parent` is a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220542/discussion-between-a-fish-and-gavin-wright).